# preg_match string starting with 'DO' and followed by any characters

Tags: php, regex

This is my starting regex that is not working:

```
'/^(DO)(?<cmd>.{1,6})$/'
```

The expression should match any string starting with 'DO', the string after 'DO' must be of minimum 1 and max 6 characters in length.

What I expect:

```
 DO // NOT A MATCH
 DO123 // MATCH
 DOaaa123 // MATCH
 DOaaa123b // NOT A MATCH
```

---

```
?<cmd>
```

is a named subpattern: matches are stored as associative array.

Comment: have you tried something like '/^(DO)(.+){1,6}$/';

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like it's a back compatibility problem, although the [documentation changelog](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) says:

> 5.2.2     Named subpatterns now accept the syntax (?) and (?'name') as well as (?P). Previous versions accepted only (?P).

Using PHP 5.4.8, windows IIS

This works fine:

```
'/^(DO)(?P<cmd>.{1,6})$/'
```

Answer (score 2):

why is there ? ?
trye `^(DO)(.{1,6})$`